# How git maintains commits from deleted branch?

Tags: git, branch, git-merge, git-commit

[image]

This is `git merge` scenario. When I merge, `New merge commit` is created, so if I go back from `New merge commit`, I can see the scheduled history of all `Master` and `Feature` branch commits till `Common base`. This is the scenario I don't understand: If I delete `Feature` branch, I think Feature branch commits will be deleted, But the reality is that when I am standing on `New merge commit`, after deleting `Feature` branch, I can still see `Feature` branch commits when I type `git log`. How is that possible? Am i mistaking something?

Comment: A branch in git is just a note, a name that points to a commit. When you delete the branch named Feature, all you're doing is removing the name that points to that commit, the commit is still there. As long as some other name (branch, tag, currently checked out commit = HEAD, etc.) is referring either directly to a commit, or indirectly through the history, the commit will not be garbage collected.

Comment: So to answer your question, no, the commit will not be deleted. It is still referenced by "New merge commit".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, a branch is just a note, a bookmark.

If you dig a bit in the `.git` directory (which I recommend you to, for educational purposes), you will see a `refs/heads` directory. It will contain one file per branch that you have locally (the remote branches are stored in `refs/remotes`).

If you open one of these files, you will see it contains a single line: the hash of the last commit the branch points to.

Deleting a branch is effectively just removing the matching file in `refs/heads`. Which is why deleting a branch does not affect the commits "of the branch" (commits don't really belong to a branch).

As a result, you can also (again, as educational purposes only, I'd not recommend to do that in a daily workflow of course) create a branch `foo` by creating the file `refs/heads/foo` with as content the **full** hash of the commit you want the branch to point to.

As a second result, as soon as a branch is merged, there is no reason to keep it around "in case".

Comment: Worth noting: sometimes `refs/heads/foo` does not exist even when branch `foo` does exist. This happens because plain files are not the only place Git stores the branch-name-to-hash-ID mapping; it also has, currently, a `.git/packed-refs` file. Because branch names are case-sensitive, but file names on Windows and MacOS often *aren't* case-sensitive, I expect Git will someday drop the idea of storing the hash IDs in files that are just named the same as the branch. Whether Git goes to a real database, or just encodes the branch names, is up to whoever fixes this bug.